# zip mime types, when to pick which one

Tags: zip, mime-types

So far for Mime Types for Zip files I've seen:

- application/octet-stream
- multipart/x-zip
- application/zip
- application/zip-compressed
- application/x-zip-compressed

I guess my question is which is the "best" and why? Why is there so many choices? I use winrar and it doesn't seem to care what the Mimetype is, but WinZip seems to only like multipart/x-zip and application/octet-stream. is there a Mimetype I can have all Zip files be downloaded as that will work in all programs?

thanks!

Comment: `application/octet-stream` stands for a generic 'whatever binary data', which can be zip as well.

Answer (score 33):

Registered with IANA MIME type is application/zip : http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/zip

WinZip is not a reference implementation (since originally ZIP standard is developed by PkWare).

Answer (score 14):

### How to recognize a valid MIME type?

- IANA maintains [a list of all registered media types and subtypes](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml).
- MIME types follow a format: `media-type/subtype-identifier`. Example: `image/png`.
- The `x-` prefix of a subtype-identifier [indicates that it is experimental and non-standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046.html#section-6) (not registered with IANA).

### Now about the zip specifically...

- `application/zip` is a standard MIME type for zip files, [officially registered with IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/zip). It seems like a good first choice :)
- `application/octet-stream` is defined in [RFC 2045 and 2046](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/octet-stream): The “octet-stream” subtype is used to indicate that a body contains arbitrary binary data, so the content can be anything, not just zip.
- `multipart/x-zip` - unlike a “discrete” type, the [“multipart” type](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2046#section-5.1) is one which represents a document that's comprised of multiple component parts, each of which may have its own individual MIME type. I suspect that the logic here is that a compressed file consists of multiple files. Thus, zip fits the “multipart” definition. But to me, it looks like overinterpretation, I would expect plain-text delimiters between parts to classify content as multipart. Moreover, it's not registered as a standard.
- `application/zip-compressed` - a non-standard type, the naming [violates RFC2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046.html#section-6): *A media type value beginning with the characters “X-” is a private value, to be used by consenting systems by mutual agreement. Any format without a rigorous and public definition must be named with an “X-” prefix*
- `application/x-zip-compressed` - some non-standard convention, I'm not sure if there is any significant usage
- `application/x-zip` - some non-standard convention, I'm not sure if there is any significant usage

Comment: apparently windows uses `x-zip-compressed` when uploading files to websites

Comment: `application/x-zip-compressed` will be yielded on Windows when the OS's MIME type database is used to identify a file based on its file name/suffix. This is probably easier than having apps build their own database, but then, users become beholden to quirks of the OS, such as this non-standard type. (This is the case for Python's `mimetypes` package. See https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/85904#issuecomment-1093883075)