# What is the mime type for .zip file?

Tags: file-upload, mime-types

What will be the mime type for .zip file for all operating systems(windows,mac,ubuntu etc.)

```
application/octet-stream
multipart/x-zip
application/zip
application/zip-compressed
application/x-zip-compressed
```

Comment: `application/zip` is a standard MIME type for zip files, officially registered with IANA. You will find more in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72232884/889779